# Lookup and set contents for one cell based on the active cell OR mouseover cell

Tags: google-sheets, mouseover, lookup

So, research has yielded 100s of answers that do not seem to simply answer the question.

I am concerned with clunkiness and best practices.  I have very little experience with Google Spreatsheets and 30+ years as a C developer.

**I want either an in the cell function to change a cell's value to a lookup based on the contents of the active cell OR
A script that very simply does the same thing with no extraneous stuff.**

I do not know how scripting is accomplished except to use the Script editor and add the script and ... it should work.  If there are other steps, I need to know them.

Likewise,

**I want either an in the cell function to change a cell's value to a lookup based on the current mouseover cursor location on the spreadsheet OR
A script that very simply does the same thing with no extraneous stuff.**

The lookup is a simple 2 column (for now) lookup where the key is in column 1 and the value I want is in column 2 at the corresponding row.

If you have some massive spreadsheet as an example please just cut and paste the relevant part as the answer to this.

Comment: There is no event detection for a mouse over of a cell.  There is an "On Edit" event, that will cause a function to run.  When the function runs you can get the active cell, and get the old value, then put a new value into the cell.  In the code editor, click the Help menu, and choose documentation.  Then search "spreadsheet" and choose SpreadsheetApp.  Always look at the return types returned by a method.  That will tell you what you can chain in the next level down.  If you are going to use Apps Script you should become familiar with the documentation.  Is this just a one time need?